# Question about allegory

Tags: grammar

Source: Doctrine of graduated escalation - (The Hindu)

What is meant by the bold part here

"Every time a Pakistani leader wishes to build better ties with New Delhi, his effort is undermined by the military masterminding a serious cross-border attack or terror strike. Indeed, it was during Mr. Sharif’s previous stint in office that a major Indian peace initiative — as symbolised by then Prime Minister Atal Bihari Vajpayee’s bus diplomacy — collapsed spectacularly, with the bus itself ***getting hijacked allegorically*** to Kargil, triggering a war." (Kargil is a place where India-Pakistan war of 1999 was fought)

I looked up a dictionary but I can't understand its meaning here. Please explain to me.

Thank you.

Comment: An allegory is a story that _symbolises_ something. In this case, the hijacking was _symbolic_: it wasn't just a bus getting hijacked, it was the bus _that symbolised the bus diplomacy_, so hijacking it symbolised _attacking the diplomatic effort_. The hijacking became an allegory of the collapse of diplomacy.

Comment: @oerkelens The real bus, so I believe, was never hijacked!

Comment: @Araucaria: it's a bit unclear to me what happened exactly, but this [google books result](http://books.google.be/books?id=L3fB0ggfwKgC&pg=PA354&lpg=PA354&dq=bus+hijack+kargil&source=bl&ots=E9Ns0bBGom&sig=-ElmZi49PfnrbT22n_54ekYgnBM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=q30-VP3LLoHvaNHegegK&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=bus%20hijack%20kargil&f=false) says the bus to Lahore got hijacked and redirected to Kargil.

Comment: @oerkelens Sorry, I stand corrected! Very interesting :)

Comment: I suspect they actually meant to say _metaphorically_, i.e. that _bus diplomacy_ is a metaphor related to the hijacking that triggered the war.

Comment: I agree with @Barmar: 'allegorically' used in this way is not normal usage in British English. I'd be interested to know if it *is* normal usage in Indian English... ?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence would be clearer if the word *allegorically* were dropped altogether and not replaced with anything:

> Indeed, it was during Mr. Sharif’s previous stint in office that a major Indian peace initiative—as symbolised by then Prime Minister Atal Bihari Vajpayee’s bus diplomacy—collapsed spectacularly, with the bus itself getting hijacked to Kargil, triggering a war.

If the author had wanted to press the point about the symbolic meaning of the real-world hijacking, he or she might then have added a sentence along the lines of this one:

> The grim symbolic significance of the diplomatic shuttle bus's real-world fate can hardly be overstated.

But there is no allegory here, and the hijacking is neither allegorical nor metaphorical.